# Managing changes to child collections and their properties

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

In Flex, how do you best manage child collection property changes, specifically
notifying a parent object that a property within the child collection
has changed.

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class Author
    {
        public var firstName:String;
        public var lastName:String;
        public var books:ArrayCollection;

        public function get dateOfFirstBookPublished():Date
        {
            if (books != null) {
                return books[0].datePublished;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}

package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class Book
    {
        public var name:String;
        public var datePublished:Date;
    }

}
```

How can I notify the Author when a Book propery has changed and update
the dateOfFirstBookPublished method? Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instance of `ArrayCollection` dispatches `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` each time you add/remove items from it. You can listen to this event.

```
author.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onChange);

public function onChange(event:CollectionEvent):void
{
    //your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you provide an example using the above classes?

Comment: @Tyler please show, how do you use dateOfFirstBookPublished()

Comment: I'd use dateOfFirstBookPublished() to return the book with the earliest datePublished. So within the method I'd sort the collection by datePublished, in ascending order, and return the book at index 0. Thus when the collection changes or a property within the book collection changes the dateOfFirstBookPublished must be aware of the change and return the correct book.

Comment: I don't see any code additions. Where did you make modifications?

Comment: @Tyler sorry, missclick. See now